# Azure web app function not triggering through crontab

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I want to implement timer based trigger based on the below article.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/manage-compute-with-azure-functions

I followed and completed each and every step. As i selected "India standard time" in template deployment, i gave the cron schedule as per Indian time. However, the scale up function did not trigger as per the scheduled time.

Can we see if any error has occurred. What could be the reason..Please reply..Let me know if any inputs are required

**Edit**

It gave me the error

> The client \'client id\' with object id \'object id\' does not have authorization to perform action \'Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/write\' over scope \'/subscriptions/subscriptionid/resourceGroups/rgname/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/dwhserver/databases/DWH_Name\

Please suggest way forward

Thanks in advance

Comment: Go to kudu `https://<functionappname>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole` and navigate to `D:\home\LogFiles\Application\Functions\Host` for detailed logs.

Comment: It gave me the error "The client \'<<client id>>\' with object id \'<<object id>>\' does not have authorization to perform 
action \'Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/write\' over scope 
\'/subscriptions/<<subscriptionid>>/resourceGroups/<<rgname>>/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/<<dwhserver>>/databases/<<DWH_Name>>\"  Please suggest way forward

Comment: Have you [Provisioned an Azure Active Directory administrator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure#provision-an-azure-active-directory-administrator-for-your-azure-sql-database-server) for data warehouse?

Comment: No.can you just tell what is it for..Is it necessary

Comment: Should be necessary since the tutorial uses [AAD authentication with Sql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication).